# delete a single blockchain

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

Not sure if this is a valid scenario for block chain apps, but just puzzled over the fact that I dont find an "uninstall/undeploy" command in the "composer network " CLI.

Is there a reason for it or is this underway and might be included in future?

Of course, the StopFabric/TearDownFabric will help to wipe everything off the face of earth and provide a clean environment, but in case of a Peer running multiple blockchains, there could be situations where we want to just get rid of just one blockchain and leave the rest as is.  In such cases, what/how should we proceed?

Answer (score 0):

a peer can get rid of a chaincode. Composer network undeploy command will disable the network permanently. To completely remove I think we have to tear down associated docker container.

Answer (score 0):

There is not currently an ability to delete a channel. The best you could do would be to remove all of the organizations from the channel. However, the ledgers hosted on the various peers previously participating would remain.